# Why do the results from normal maps differ between Eevee and Cycles?

Tags: texturing, normal-map

I am currently in the process of creating a kitchenaid mixer in Blender. I baked a normal map to create some fake engravings in the metal at the top of the model as you can see in the pictures below.

Eevee: [image]

Cycles:[image]
My node setup for the upper ring:
[image]

The results in Eevee are way better then those in Cycles. The letters pop out much better. I have the same node setup in both renders. My guess is that i have to change something in the setup in Cycles, but i don't know what. Is there a way to get the same results of the normals in Cycles as you do in Eevee?

Comment: Basically, Eevee isn't stopping the light from "bouncing" off of a surface at an impossible angle. Because of this, you can see reflections of lights that are actually behind the surface.

Comment: So does that mean that it's not possible to create the same effect you get in Eevee? Should I use a displacement map instead if I wanted to make my final render in Cycles?

Comment: Displacement vs normal map is up to you (displacement will be more accurate of course), but I think the most important thing to tweak here is your lighting.